# Why is this sum zero?

Tags: summation

I have been looking at the following sum (for any positive integer $n$)

$$\left(1-\frac{1^2}{n}\right) + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2^2}{n}\right) + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3^2}{n}\right) + \ldots $$

Note that the $i$th term in the sum has $i$ factors and  is

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)\dots \left(1-\frac{i-1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{i^2}{n}\right).$$

It seems, amazingly, that the answer is 0. How can one show this?

Comment: I think there should be $(1-1/n)(1-2^2/n)(1-3^2/n)$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif I think it's correct as I have written it.

Comment: @Lembik: If that's the case, what is the form of the $i$th term? Like Oussama, I thought it was $(1-1^2/n)(1-2^2/n)(1-3^2/n)\dots(1-i^2/n)$. Are you saying that it's $(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)\dots(1-i^2/n)$?

Comment: @Lembik aah so basically it's like this?: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{k^2}{n})\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac{k}{n})$

Comment: @DivergentQueries Yes exactly. It is $(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)\dots(1-i^2/n)$

Comment: Can you fix the formula in the question then please. As it stands, the second term has two factors rather than four and the third term has three factors rather than nine.

Comment: @RobArthan, the ith term has i factors, of which only the last one has a squared numerator.

Comment: Perhaps it would be clearer if the first term is shown as $(1-\frac{1^2}n)$.

Comment: Then your comment should say $(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)\ldots(1-(i-1)/n)(1-i^2/n)$ (and you should include that in the statement of your question).

Comment: In the summation formula given in one of the comments above the term after the product sign should read $(1-\frac in)$ instead of $(1-\frac kn)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following holds true for $n\geq 1$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)=0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Note, the empty product is set equal to $1$. We start by transforming the product into a somewhat more convenient form .

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}&\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n^{k-1}}\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(n-j)\tag{2}\\
> &=n!\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\frac{1}{n^k}\frac{1}{(n-k)!}\\
> &=\frac{n!}{n^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1-\frac{(n-k)^2}{n}\right)\frac{n^k}{k!}\tag{3}\\
> \end{align*}

In (2) we set the upper limit of the sum to $n$ since for values greater than $n$ the product contains a factor zero. In the last step (3) we changed the index summation $k\rightarrow n-k$. In the following we skip the factor $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ and show the sum is equal to zero.

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}&\left(1-\frac{(n-k)^2}{n}\right)\frac{n^k}{k!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-n^2+2kn-k^2)\frac{n^k}{k!}\\
> &=(1-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\frac{n^k}{k!}
> -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}k(k-1)\frac{n^k}{k!}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\frac{n^k}{k!}\tag{4}\\
> &=(1-n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}+2n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^k}{k!}
> -n\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\frac{n^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{n^k}{k!}\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-n\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+n\frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}\\
> &=\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left(1-n+(n-1)\right)\\
> &=0\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we set the lower bounds of the index accordingly and use $k^2=k(k-1)+k$ to be able to cancel out factors of the factorial conveniently.
- In (5) we adjust the index accordingly to obtain equal summands for telescoping in the next step.

> **Added 2015-08-13:** A note to the elegant approach of @BarryCipra due to a comment of @hypergeometric.
>
> Let $R$ be a positive integer less than $n$. We obtain from (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}&\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{R}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)+
> \sum_{k=R+1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\\
> &=\prod_{r=1}^R\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{R}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=k}^R\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)^{-1}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left.\sum_{k=R+1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=R+1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=\prod_{r=1}^R\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\left(R+\sum_{k=R+1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=R+1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)\right)\tag{7}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- Observe the last line of @BarryCipras representation corresponds to (7) with $R=3$.
- Since we know that (7) is valid, we proceed from (6) to (7) by claiming the validity of the identity

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{R}\left(1-\frac{k^2}{n}\right)\prod_{j=k}^R\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)^{-1}=R\qquad\qquad 1\leq R < n
\end{align*}

This identity is a nice by-product.

- When setting $R\geq n$ in (7) we observe, that the leftmost product contains a factor zero. But we can't use this argument in this derivation, since we have to consider in (6) the factors $\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)^{-1}$ which are undefined in case $j=n$.

Comment: Very nice (+1). Are we also able to show that it is equivalent to $\prod_{r=1}^n(1-\frac rn)$ as shown in the answer by Barry Cipra above?

Comment: @hypergeometric: Thanks for upvoting and yes, it should be possible (of course :-)) I'll try to add some helpful information soon.

Comment: @hypergeometric: Note added. Not a proof, but at least providing some aspects.

Answer (score 15):

This might get you started:

$$\begin{align}
&\left(1-{1^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(1-{3^2\over n}\right)+\cdots\\
&\quad=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1+\left(1-{2^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(1-{3^2\over n}\right)+\cdots \right)\\
&\quad=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(\left(2-{2^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(1-{3^2\over n}\right)+\cdots \right)\\
&\quad=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(2+\left(1-{3^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{3\over n}\right)\left(1-{4^2\over n}\right)+\cdots \right)\\
&\quad=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(\left(3-{3^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{3\over n}\right)\left(1-{4^2\over n}\right)+\cdots \right)\\
&\quad=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\left(1-{2\over n}\right)\left(1-{3\over n}\right)\left(3+\left(1-{4^2\over n}\right)+\left(1-{4\over n}\right)\left(1-{5^2\over n}\right)+\cdots \right)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very clever indeed (+1). $1-\frac nn=0$. Long-hand expansion rules. Can this be written using summation and product symbols?

Comment: @hypergeometric  And $1-\frac{n}{n}$ comes from $n-1+(1-\frac{n^2}{n})$

Comment: I think it is clear from the solution that this eventually reduces to $\prod_{r=1}^n(1-\frac rn)$ with the last term being zero.

Answer (score 2):

This becomes somewhat less mysterious once we recognize that every term after the $n$th term includes $\left(1-\frac{n}{n}\right)=0$.

Comment: Okay, so the numbers stop, but why do the first few add up to zero?

Comment: This was intended as a hint to show that we can pose the question in finite terms, but I can edit my answer to include the explicit solution.

Comment: Why every term after $n^2$? Won't it be every term after the $\sqrt(n)$th term?

Comment: @Gummybears That would require $n$ to be a perfect square wouldn't it?

Comment: @Lembik Ehhhn then take it to be closest integer equal to or greater than $\sqrt{n}$. The $n^2$ is......

Comment: @Gummybears: You need to evaluate the sum to at least $n$ terms to get $0$. This is fine, since OP's sum was implied to be infinite.

Comment: Well obviously. But after a certain term, they will all be zero. I guess it won't make a difference though.

Comment: @Lembik: my "mistake" was caused by your misleading comment that suggests the $i$-th term has $i^2$ factors.

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums are 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
1/2&0\\
2/3&4/9&0\\
3/4&12/16&18/64&0\\
4/5&24/25&72/125&96/625&0\\
5/6&40/36&180/216&480/1296&600/6^5&0\end{eqnarray}$$
The ratios from one partial sum to the next are 
$$\begin{eqnarray}0\\
2/3&0\\
4/4&(3/2)/4&0\\
6/5&(6/2)/5&(4/3)/5&0\\
8/6&(9/2)/6&(8/3)/6&(5/4)/6&0\end{eqnarray}$$
So is the sum of the first $k$ terms, with $n$ as the key variable, 
$$\frac{\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-1-k)!}k}{n^k}$$